# Compare a few columns for 2 different dates in same table, return what is different?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a simple table that contains (a rolling) 2 BUSINESS_DATES of data.  Each day I want to compare the data for each of those dates and return what has NEW and CHANGED.  Unfortunately there is no primary key.  A sample of the table looks like this.

```
BUSINESS_DATE    EMPLOYEE_ID       DEPT ACCESS       ACTIVE      CREATE_DATE      APPROVED_BY
-------------    ------------      --------    ------------     -------------     ------------
8/28/2022        1                 dept 1            Y           1/1/2022         john          
8/28/2022        1                 dept 3            Y           1/1/2022         john         
8/28/2022        1                 dept 6            Y           1/1/2022         john        
8/28/2022        2                 dept 1            Y           1/1/2022         john        
8/28/2022        2                 dept 2            Y           1/1/2022         john        
8/28/2022        2                 dept 3            Y           1/1/2022         john        
8/28/2022        2                 dept 4            Y           1/1/2022         john        

8/29/2022        1                 dept 1            Y           1/1/2022         john          
8/29/2022        1                 dept 3            Y           1/1/2022         john         
8/29/2022        1                 dept 6            N           1/1/2022         john        * CHANGED (active flag)    
8/29/2022        1                 dept 4            Y           1/1/2022         john        * NEW
8/29/2022        2                 dept 1            Y           1/1/2022         john        
8/29/2022        2                 dept 2            Y           1/1/2022         john        
8/29/2022        2                 dept 3            Y           1/1/2022         john        
8/29/2022        2                 dept 4            Y           1/1/2022         john
```

So in the data above I'd like to return the 2 rows I've marked * and if possible be able to create a new column that identifies whether it's a NEW entry/row or a CHANGED row/entry.

I tried playing around with FULL OUTER JOINS but I wasn't getting the results I was hoping for.  Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!!  By the way using SQL 2016 in case that is relevant.

Comment: Is the comparison between just the `dept access` and `active` columns? Is `dept access` unique per `employee_id`? What is the relevance to the question of the `create_date` and `Approved_by` columns, could rows be duplicate apart from values in either of these columns? can there be gaps in `business_date`?

Comment: hey @Stu thanks.  There will only be 2 business dates in the table at a time.  Comparison should include CREATE_DATE and APPROVED in case someone makes a modification to either of those.  DEPT ACCESS is not unique per EMPLOYEE ID, any EMPLOYEE ID can get granted access to any and every DEPT ACCESS if that makes sense.  Does this help? Thanks!

Comment: If dept_access is not unique per employeee then if the following business day  has 2 rows with the same dept access eg 2 rows with `dept 1`, which one is to be marked as new? and what if a row is missing the following business day?

Comment: I'm sorry @Stu maybe I answered incorrectly.  There will be no duplicate row for the same business date.  So I should have said yes the combo of EMPLOYEE ID, DEPT, ACTIVE, CREATE DATE, APPROVED will be unique.  If a NEW record is created it will be a new EMPLOYEE ID and DEPT ACCESS that wasn't there the previous day.  If a record is modified it basically means ACTIVE, CREATE DATE or APPROVED BY was changed.  A row will never be deleted,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you would need a full join if the latest date must have at least as many rows as the prior day:

```
select d0.*,
    case when d1.EMPLOYEE_ID is null then 'New'
         when d1.ACTIVE <> d0.ACTIVE or d1.CREATE_DATE <> d0.CREATE_DATE
           or d1.APPROVED_BY <> d0.APPROVED_BY then 'Changed'
         else 'Unmodified' end as Status
from T d0 left outer join T d1
    on     d1.EMPLOYEE_ID = d0.EMPLOYEE_ID and d1.DEPT = d0.DEPT
           /* this would readily handle weekend/holiday gaps */
       and d1.BUSINESS_DATE < d0.BUSINESS_DATE 
where d0.BUSINESS_DATE = cast(getdate() as date);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I believe it is working properly.  Still trying to continue testing on new examples as they come in.  Appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

One way you could consider is outer joining using *apply* and a *checksum* for comparing changes, such as:

```
with c as (
  select *, 
    Checksum(ACTIVE, CREATE_DATE, APPROVED_BY) chk, 
    Dense_Rank() over(order by BUSINESS_DATE) rnk
  from t
)
select c.BUSINESS_DATE, c.EMPLOYEE_ID, c.DEPT_ACCESS, c.ACTIVE, c.CREATE_DATE, c.APPROVED_BY, 
  Iif(rnk = 1, '', IsNull(d.NewStatus, 'New'))
from c
outer apply(
  select case when c2.chk = c.chk then '' else 'Changed' end
  from c c2
  where c2.BUSINESS_DATE < c.BUSINESS_DATE
    and c2.EMPLOYEE_ID = c.EMPLOYEE_ID
    and c2.DEPT_ACCESS = c.DEPT_ACCESS
)d(NewStatus)
order by BUSINESS_DATE, EMPLOYEE_ID;
```

Comment: Appreciate this!  I ended up trying out the other answer and I believe that is working for me.  I'll continue testing as new examples come in.  If I run into trouble I may come back to this but I wanted to say thanks for the help and I bumped it up!